# Can't get the right link from a img tag in cheerio. Getting a wrong format for the link

Tags: node.js, cheerio

so i'm scraping an e-commerce site from which i want to get some data about the products. i'm getting all the data i need but getting a weird format for the image link: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" instead of "https://tn.jumia.is/D8RjVA7gYqsaxxwKgqOa_6582_k=/fit-in/220x220/filters:fill(white):sharpen(1,0,false):quality(100)/product/48/9141/1.jpg?5043"

i tried the same scraper for other sites and it did work  fine.

```
const link = "https://www.jumia.com.tn/smartphones/"

var categorieTag = ".osh-cat-header .title";
var siteTag = ".logo a img";
var productEnvelopeTag = ".sku";
var imageLinkTag = ".image-wrapper img  ";
var productNameTag = ".name";
var priceTag = ".price";
var currencyTag = ".data-currency-iso";
var availabilityTag = "#stock_availability";
var productRefTag = ".product-reference";
var productLink = ".product-title a";

function getHtmlSite() {
  return fetch(`${link}`).then(response => response.text());
}
getHtmlSite().then(body => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var $categorie = $(categorieTag)
    .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
    .text();
  var $site = $(siteTag);
  $(productEnvelopeTag).each(function(i, element) {
    const $image = $(element).find(imageLinkTag);
    const $productName = $(element).find(productNameTag);
    const $price = $(element).find(priceTag);
    const $currencyTag = $(element).find(currencyTag);
    const $availability = $(element).find(availabilityTag);
    const $refProduct = $(element).find(productRefTag);
    const $productLink = $(element).find(productLink);
    product = {
      image: $image.attr("src"),
      productName: $productName.text(),
      price: $price.text().trim(),
      currencyTag: $currencyTag.text().trim(),
      categorie: $categorie,
      availability: $availability.text().trim(),
      site: $site.attr("alt"),
      refProduct: $refProduct.text(),
      prodcutLink: $productLink.attr("href")
    };

    allProducts.push(product);
  });

  fs.writeFileSync("JumiaProducts.json", JSON.stringify(allProducts, null, 2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the data-src attribute for those:

```
image: $image.attr("data-src")
```

Sometimes you need to look at the "view-source" html instead of element inspector.

Comment: it didn't work, i don't get the image in the json file output with "data-src".

Comment: Just set a breakpoint and inspect $image, there's probably an issue there.